# What's in the DNS Debug Log Message Fields

Tags: domain-name-system, logging, logparser

I've [enable debug logging options on the DNS server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759581(v=ws.10).aspx), and I'm trying to parse through the output in dns.log.  Here's a guide from technet on how to [use server debug logging options](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776361(v=ws.10).aspx), but I can't find anything authoritative as to what the standard format for each field would be, let alone when details are included.

Here's a sample log line from the question [What Do the Numbers In Parentheses Mean In My Windows DNS Debug Log?](https://serverfault.com/q/513538/176522):

```
6/5/2013 10:00:32 AM 0E70 PACKET  00000000033397A0 UDP Rcv 10.161.60.71    5b47   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (12)somecomputer(6)domain(3)com(0)
```

Unfortunately, that answer didn't go into what any of the other fields mean.

Technet's [How DNS Works](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772774(v=ws.10).aspx) gives a good review of some of the fields, but nothing specific to the debug log formatting.

What are all the fields?

Bonus points for a powershell script that parses the info.

Answer (score 2):

> **Note**: This answer is potentially incomplete as is.  I've tried to add as much information as I could find to help carry the torch as far as possible, but I've added it as a community Wiki in hopes that other users will update incomplete or incorrect information.

According to the question [DNS debug log dns.log Format Review](http://answers.splunk.com/answers/132364/dns-debug-log-dns-log-format-review.html), the fields map as follows

```
Date and Time             Type                     Prot Dir Request IP           R/Q             Flag     Record Domain
6/5/2013 10:00:32 AM 0E70 PACKET  00000000033397A0 UDP  Rcv 10.161.60.71    5b47   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (12)somecomputer(6)domain(3)com(0)
```

Here's a list of the field level info:

- **Date and Time** - Date and time of DNS traffic
- **Type** - The type of DNS traffic
- **Prot** - The Protocol being used [TCP|UDP]
- **Dir** - The Direction - [**Rec**eiving|**Sen**ding]
- **Request IP** - The IP address of the requesting client
- **R/Q** - **R**esponse / Re**q**uest
- **Flag** - DNS Update Message Flags
- **Record Type** - The Type of DNS Record
- **Domain** - The domain that was originally requested

### Lookups

Here's a list of potential lookup values for each of the categories:

**Flag Lookup**:

- **NOERROR**  - `0` - No error; successful update.
- **FORMERR**  - `1` - Format error; DNS server did not understand the update request.
- **SERVFAIL** - `0x2` - DNS server encountered an internal error, such as a forwarding timeout
- **NXDOMAIN** - `0x3` - A name that should exist does not exist.
- **NOTIMP**   - `0x4` - DNS server does not support the specified Operation code.
- **REFUSED**  - `0x5` - DNS server refuses to perform the update because
- **YXDOMAIN** - `0x6` - A name that should not exist does exist.
- **YXRRSET**  - `0x7` - A resource record set that should not exist does exist.
- **NXRRSET**  - `0x8` - A resource record set that should exist does not exist.
- **NOTAUTH**  - `0x9` - DNS server is not authoritative for the zone named in the Zone section.
- **NOTZONE**  - `0xA` - A name used in the Prerequisite or Update sections is not within the zone specified by the Zone section.

**Record Type Lookup**:

- **A** -     `0x01` - Host record
- **NS** -    `0x02` - Name server record
- **CNAME** - `0x05` - Alias record
- **PTR** -   `0x0C` - Reverse-lookup record
- **MX** -    `0x0F` - Mail exchange record
- **SRV** -   `0x21` - Service record
- **IXFR** -  `0xFB` - Incremental zone transfer record
- **AXFR** -  `0xFC` - Standard zone transfer record
- **All** -   `0xFF` - All records Domain

### Parsing Script

Here's a cmdlet from Arun Sabale on [Read DNS debug log and generate output in readable CSV format](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Read-DNS-debug-log-and-532a8504).

After running the cmdlet, you can call it like this:

```ps
Get-DNSDebugLog -DNSLog ".\DnsDebug.log" | Export-Csv .\ProperlyFormatedLog.csv
```

**Script**:

```ps
###########################################################################
# NAME: read DNS debug logs
# AUTHOR:  Arun Sabale
# COMMENT: 
# VERSION HISTORY:
# 1.0  - Initial release
###########################################################################

function Get-DNSDebugLog
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    This cmdlet parses a Windows DNS Debug log.

    .DESCRIPTION
    When a DNS log is converted with this cmdlet it will be turned into objects for further parsing.

    .EXAMPLE
    Get-DNSDebugLog -DNSLog ".\Something.log" | Format-Table

    Outputs the contents of the dns debug file "Something.log" as a table.

    .EXAMPLE
    Get-DNSDebugLog -DNSLog ".\Something.log" | Export-Csv .\ProperlyFormatedLog.csv

    Turns the debug file into a csv-file.

    .PARAMETER DNSLog
    Path to the DNS log or DNS log data. Allows pipelining from for example Get-ChildItem for files, and supports pipelining DNS log data.

    #>

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
      [Alias('Fullname')]
      [string] $DNSLog = "StringMode")


    BEGIN { }

    PROCESS {

        $TheReverseRegExString="\(\d\)in-addr\(\d\)arpa\(\d\)"

        ReturnDNSLogLines -DNSLog $DNSLog | % {
            if ( $_ -match "^\d\d" -AND $_ -notlike "*EVENT*") {
                $Date=$null
                $Time=$null
                $DateTime=$null
                $Protocol=$null
                $Client=$null
                $SendReceive=$null
                $QueryType=$null
                $RecordType=$null
                $Query=$null
                $Result=$null

                $Date=($_ -split " ")[0]

                # Check log time format and set properties
                if ($_ -match ":\d\d AM|:\d\d  PM") {
                    $Time=($_ -split " ")[1,2] -join " "
                    $Protocol=($_ -split " ")[7]
                    $Client=($_ -split " ")[9]
                    $SendReceive=($_ -split " ")[8]
                    $RecordType=(($_ -split "]")[1] -split " ")[1]
                    $Query=($_.ToString().Substring(110)) -replace "\s" -replace "\(\d?\d\)","." -replace "^\." -replace "\.$"
                    $Result=(((($_ -split "\[")[1]).ToString().Substring(9)) -split "]")[0] -replace " "
                }
                elseif ($_ -match "^\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d \d\d:") {
                    $Date=$Date.Substring(0,4) + "-" + $Date.Substring(4,2) + "-" + $Date.Substring(6,2)
                    $Time=($_ -split " ")[1] -join " "
                    $Protocol=($_ -split " ")[6]
                    $Client=($_ -split " ")[8]
                    $SendReceive=($_ -split " ")[7]
                    $RecordType=(($_ -split "]")[1] -split " ")[1]
                    $Query=($_.ToString().Substring(110)) -replace "\s" -replace "\(\d?\d\)","." -replace "^\." -replace "\.$"
                    $Result=(((($_ -split "\[")[1]).ToString().Substring(9)) -split "]")[0] -replace " "
                }
                else {
                    $Time=($_ -split " ")[1]
                    $Protocol=($_ -split " ")[6]
                    $Client=($_ -split " ")[8]
                    $SendReceive=($_ -split " ")[7]
                    $RecordType=(($_ -split "]")[1] -split " ")[1]
                    $Query=($_.ToString().Substring(110)) -replace "\s" -replace "\(\d?\d\)","." -replace "^\." -replace "\.$"
                    $Result=(((($_ -split "\[")[1]).ToString().Substring(9)) -split "]")[0] -replace " "
                }

                $DateTime=Get-Date("$Date $Time") -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"


                if ($_ -match $TheReverseRegExString) {
                    $QueryType="Reverse"
                }
                else {
                    $QueryType="Forward"
                }

                $returnObj = New-Object System.Object
                $returnObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Date -Value $DateTime
                $returnObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name QueryType -Value $QueryType
                $returnObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Client -Value $Client
                $returnObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name SendReceive -Value $SendReceive
                $returnObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Protocol -Value $Protocol
                $returnObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name RecordType -Value $RecordType
                $returnObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Query -Value $Query
                $returnObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Results -Value $Result

                if ($returnObj.Query -ne $null) {
                    Write-Output $returnObj
                }
            }
        }

    }

    END { }
}



function ReturnDNSLogLines
{
param(
$DNSLog)

$PathCorrect=try { Test-Path $DNSLog -ErrorAction Stop } catch { $false }

    if ($DNSLog -match "^\d\d" -AND $DNSLog -notlike "*EVENT*" -AND $PathCorrect -ne $true) {
        $DNSLog
    }
    elseif ($PathCorrect -eq $true) {
        Get-Content $DNSLog | % { $_ }
    }
}
```